# " document.getElementById("").value" dosn't work in my visual studio code

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I am new in JS, and I tried to get my input's value by the code shown below :

`var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value`

But Intellisense doesn't show me "value". When I write ".va", it shows me "nodeValue" and it doesn't show me "value" in the autocomplete options at all.

```js
var lbl = document.getElementById("lblResult");
lbl.innerHTML = "Ok";

function Sum() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

  num1 = parseInt(num1);
  num2 = parseInt(num2);
  var sum = num1 + num2;
  lbl.innerHTML = sum;
};
```

```html
<h2 id="lblResult">salam</h2>
Number 1 : <input type="number" id="num1" />
<br /> Number 2 : <input type="number" id="num2" />
<br />
<input type="submit" onclick="Sum();" value="sum">
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Put it inside the `body` maybe?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` should be first. Why do you repeat head? As @AlonEitan said, first make sure, you are using valid HTML.

Comment: @Teemu Your last edit removed all the HTML issues in the original code

Comment: Your code seems to work as it is ..? Where exactly is the value "_nodeValue_" shown?

Comment: @AlonEitan The issues with HTML don't cause results OP says they get. I suspect those being in the post only. But I'm not going to start a roll-back war, if you want to roll-back my edit.

Comment: @Teemu I think OP has issues specifically with VS-Code. (i.e. autocomplete not working or it not recognizing `.value` as a valid property.)

Comment: My codes work, but as you said, i think autocomplete dosn't work !

Comment: @HosseinDara Use a tool like W3C's [Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to make sure your HTML is valid first. That _could_ already solve the problem.

Comment: @HosseinDara Can you confirm you've only a singe head element in your real code? If that's not the case, we can roll-back the question to contain your real code.

Comment: When i write ".va", the intellisense shows me "nodeValue" and it dosn't show me any "value"

Comment: I've added that comment to the question itself. Now people know what is the actual issue.

Comment: I can't reprocude your issue with VS Code either, I'm getting "value" as the first option when writing `.va` in a JS file.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't Know why I can't get "value" !

Comment: if you're writing typescript, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76891732/11107541

Answer (score 2):

You might need to indicate the type of element because `document.getElementById` can also return other element that will have no `value` attribute. For example `h2` element with `id: lblResult`. VsCode uses `TS` for it's intellisense.

Use below JSDoc comment with the type.

```js
var lbl = document.getElementById("lblResult");
lbl.innerHTML = "Ok";

function Sum() {
  /**
   * Indicate your element type will be HTMLInputElement
   * @type HTMLInputElement
   */
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

  num1 = parseInt(num1);
  num2 = parseInt(num2);
  var sum = num1 + num2;
  lbl.innerHTML = sum;
};
```

More on JSDoc: [JSDoc reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html)

Comment: I don't know how can i use this? can u describe it for me ?

Comment: @HosseinDara You need to add the comment that I have provided inside the `Sum()` function. Another work around will be to remove `TypeScript` globally, re-install and then restart the VSCode.