# How to fix the issue that TypeScript says value is not part of input element

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have been doing this in JavaScript and now trying it using TypeScript:

```html
    <input id="field" value="hello" />

    
    <script>
      // @ts-check

      const el = document.querySelector("#field");
      console.log(el, el?.value);
    </script>
```

and Visual Studio Code's TypeScript checker is giving me a red squiggly line for the `value` in `el?.value`, saying `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'`.

[image]

It seems I can use `el.getAttribute("value");` but does that mean I have to change all the JS code to TS in such a way? Is there a way to tell TS to accept `value`?  This applies to both VSC and in case I need to use `tsc` or any build tool.

Comment: `querySelector`'s return type is a generic Element. You need to assert it's an input: `const el = document.querySelector("#field") as HTMLInputElement;`.

Comment: so I can also use `const el: HTMLInputElement | null = document.querySelector("#field");` it seems?

Comment: if you're writing javascript, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66734630/11107541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, since `querySelector` returns `Element | null`, TypeScript can't know `value` is a valid property unless you manually declare its type.

There are several ways to achieve this:

1. use `as` keyword.

   ```js
   const el = document.querySelector("#id") as HTMLInputElement
   ```
2. complete the generic.

   ```
   const el = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>("#id")
   ```

   You can find more information about TypeScript generic in [this doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

---

> but does that mean I have to change all the JS code to TS in such a way?

No. TS is designed to be compatible with JS, and every JS script should run successfully after you change the suffix from `.js(x)` to `.ts(x)`. The common problem is that you may fail the type checking provided by `tsc` after you migrate JS to TS. It may be a little painful as you will see a lot of errors/warnings.

The guideline is that you DON'T have to change the logic of your code. Just add necessary type declarations (function, variable and so on). To narrow the type scope (for example, from `HTMLElement` to `HTMLInputElement`), `as` keyword is enough for most situations.

Comment: Be wary that using the `as` keyword will make assumptions about the result of `document.querySelector`, and you could run into issues should `el` be `null`, the second option provided is much safer and clearer, it still allows for `null` to be returned and the compiler would then prompt you (the developer) to ensure that you have checked for the `null` value. (Not a criticism of this answer, it's very well written)